# Issue of AngularJS ng-model providing "Status" of application data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why the `Touched` value in the [following](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_model_status) is always "true" whether or not the cursor is inside or outside of the input box? Is there something I may not be understanding here? The `Valid` and `Dirty` values work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<form ng-app="" name="myForm" ng-init="myText = 'post@myweb.com'">

Email:
<input type="email" name="myAddress" ng-model="myText" required>
<p>Edit the e-mail address, and try to change the status.</p>
<h1>Status</h1>
<p>Valid: {{myForm.myAddress.$valid}} (if true, the value meets all criteria).</p>
<p>Dirty: {{myForm.myAddress.$dirty}} (if true, the value has been changed).</p>
<p>Touched: {{myForm.myAddress.$touched}} (if true, the field has been in focus).</p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Initially it is false and becomes true on blur, this is the meaning of `$touched`

Comment: @BillP But when it losses focus it remains true. For example, if you highlight any word (for instance `Edit` or `address`) by double clicking on it, you are certainly outside input box that means input box is out of focus - and hence `touched ` should have value false.

Comment: `$touched` means that input has been touched. Once the user blurs the form control $touched sets and remains true, this is how it works

Comment: $pristine/$dirty tells you whether the user actually changed anything, while $touched/$untouched tells you whether the user has merely been there/visited.

Comment: @stotomo Oh, I see now. So, it's `has been in focus` vs. `is in focus`. So, `$touched` means: `has been in focus`, that is, user has merely been there/visited. Thank you for explaining the real purpose of `$touched`.

Comment: @BillP Got it now. Thank you.